# Most performant way to create a JavaScript collection with generated IDs

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to create a object like this:

```
{
  columns: ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz"],
  rows: {
    0: [0,1,2],
    1: [3,4,5],
  },
  cells: {
    0: "First Cell, First Row",
    1: "Second Cell, First Row",
    2: "Third Cell, First Row",
    3: "First Cell, Second Row",
    4: "Second Cell, Second Row",
    5: "Third Cell, Second Row"
  }
}
```

Where the numeric object keys are the row IDs and cell IDs. Creating the object itself isn't hard, but the part where I create the rows' arrays seems overly complex with what I'm doing.

Right now I'm doing, for each row, for each column, push `cellId++` like this

```
  var cellId = 0;
  data.rows.forEach(function (row, rowId) {
    newData.rows[rowId] = [];
    data.columns.forEach(function (column, columnId) {
      newData.rows[rowId].push(cellId++);
    });
  });
```

What I'd love is something like (in pseudo code)

```
  data.rows.forEach(function (row, rowId) {
    newData.rows[rowId] = new Array({startAt: 0, endAt: 2});
  });
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: You say "performant" in the title of your question, then say "I'd love" in the text of your question, presumably because it's more compact. Could you clarify whether you are interested in performance vs. compactness. Anyway, won't `map` do the job for you, probably using the "index" parameter to the callback?

Comment: Performant would be best. My compact example above is less about the compactness and more about the fact it's not doing a nested loop and tracking multiple things.

Comment: The fastest way would be nested for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` should help you:

```
var cellId = 0;
  data.rows.forEach(function (row, rowId) {
    newData.rows[rowId] = data.columns.map(function() { return cellId++; });
  });
```

Or use it for both dimensions:

```
newData = data.rows.map(function() {
  return data.columns.map(function() { 
    return cellId++;
  });
})
```

Comment: Marked this as the right answer because you commented above that the actual answer for performant is the nested loops, but if you come to this question looking for compactness your map solution is very compact. Thanks!